# I can't access routes via https in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, https, deployment

I built an application with express of node.js.

```js
const express = require('express');  // servidor de desenvolvimento
const app = express();

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`http://localhost:3000`);
});
```

when I run the server and try access it with `https://my_local_IP:port` in browser I get `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`, but if I use `https://my_local_IP:port` it works.

How do I make the app to listen in on http port, even to requests in https port?

Comment: You have to use an SSL certificate for the browser to allow it.

Comment: You can create a self signed certificate and use it

Comment: Without the browser allowing your request, it won't reach the express server.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an SSL certificate on the server you're running express on. You can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907102/how-can-i-configure-expressjs-to-handle-both-http-and-https) for more information on how to do that

Comment: thanks, bro. i found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397809/create-a-trusted-self-signed-ssl-cert-for-localhost-for-use-with-express-node)